# Why can't I create an ActiveRecord entry like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two associated models:

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_accounts
end

Class CompanyAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
end
```

I want to create a CompanyAccount for an existing user. This works:

```
@user.company_accounts.create
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
CompanyAccount.create(user_id: @user.id)
```

The full error message is "Users must exist". I'm using rails 5.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `belongs_to :user`, it has only one user not many.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Could you explain why the first command works and the second not when I use `:users`?

Comment: I am not sure in 100% but in first you have @user.company_accounts.create so rails are building you a proper query, in second you have CompanyAccount.create so you don't have user in this scoped attributes. You can replicate it using this: `company_accounts = CompanyAccount.where(user_id: @user.id)` and then `company_accounts.create` . It has so touch belongs_to in other ways, but i cant replicate it now so i am not sure where is the difference.

Comment: Ok i found some sort of explanation http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html , as i understand, rails are looking for model 'users' to compare it and find proper 'users' but you have model 'user' so it cant find it, error is a bit misleading. In first you have already defined user in scoped attributes so rails 5 are not looking for him. (user had a proper association name)